# update react child component's state using props received from an async api call made in the parent component

Tags: reactjs, state, lifecycle, react-props

what i want to do is to set my state using props but the problem is my props come from an api call made in the parent component(I am using react router dom). So first I tried using componentDidMount which works when you go to Home(Child) from welcome page(child) but when you directly come to home page component did mount fills the state before the api call is made(so undefined basically).

next I tried using componentDidUpdate which works when you go directly to the Home(child) but componentDidUpdate does not even fire when you go from welcome page(child) to Home(child).(so undefined again) (componentdidupdate does'nt run when component is initialized i.e first time component made)
also if you navigate to another route and come back it does'nt work in componentDidUpdate's case **i think component lifecycle starts from the very beginning could someone please confirm this??**

Now I am using both componentDidUpdate and componentDidMount in my code and it is working good. I just wish to know is this the best way or is there another way to **populate state using props from an api call**

Home component

```
constructor(props: HomeProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      myUser: {},
    }
  }


  componentDidUpdate = (prevProps: HomeProps) => {
    if (prevProps.userProfile.ID !== this.props.userProfile.ID) {
      this.setState({ myUser: this.props.userProfile });
    }
  }

componentDidMount = () => {
    this.setState({ myUser: this.props.userProfile })
  }
```

main Component(parent)
welcome: path="/"
Home:  path="/Home"

```
<HashRouter>
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => (<Welcome {...props} />)} />
                   <Route exact path="/Home" render={(props) => (<Home authContext={this.props.authContext} {...props} userProfile={this.state.currentUser} />)} />
</Switch>
</HashRouter>
```

just wish to know the right way and i'll also appreciate if you can explain why it is better.

Comment: Home is not a child of Welcome. They're both at the same level and only one of will be rendered due to Switch.

Comment: yes they are, I have updated the question and changed landing to welcome

Answer (score 1):

The way I would structure this would be rather than having the different Routes as Parent - Child, I would consider them as parallel or siblings. And in that scenario I would use Redux or your preferred state management. As your app grows and you add more routes, you'd have to then pass the user prop from your Parent route to all the future routes, and it's going to be more of a problem to maintain.

With using a state management tool like Redux, all components would have access to the state, no need to pass props to each component no matter how deep the route goes or how many sibling routes you add.

Answer (score 1):

first u should use async/await api call and u can use like below if u use async/await in api itself solve this issue.

```
   constructor(props: HomeProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          myUser: {},
        }
      }        
      componentDidUpdate = async(prevProps: HomeProps) => {
        if (prevProps.userProfile.ID !== this.props.userProfile.ID) {
        await  this.setState({ myUser: this.props.userProfile });
        }
      }        
   componentDidMount = async () => {
       await this.setState({ myUser: this.props.userProfile })
      }
```